# Is it frowned upon to ask a new question with the explicit intent of creating a broader version of a question that was already asked?

Tags: discussion

[This question about being stuck in the story](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/294055/how-to-get-to-aether-paradise) was just asked. I was going to answer it, but then I realized it might be worth it to create and answer a more general question about being stuck anywhere in the story, rather than that specific point, with the intent of then closing that user's question as a duplicate of the new question I was going to ask, so that new questions about being stuck in the story can be easily answered under the broader question.

This stems from the fact that there is a way to always, at any point in the story, check where the next objective is located and what the player needs to accomplish there.

Ideally, that's how I'd proceed, but some people have expressed concerns that this kind of behaviour might be perceived as rude towards the user who asked the question I linked. What is the appropriate course of action?

Comment: Sometimes this is fine, but I'm not sure the case you are proposing would really work. if a player could (conceivably) get stuck anywhere along the story, an answer would have to be *a complete walkthrough of the entire game*, and that seems a little too broad in scope.

Comment: @TrentHawkins There's a way to check where you're supposed to go next at any point in the story, which would suit a more general question.

Comment: Ah, that may work then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the game does provide a way in-game to check what they should be doing next to advance the story, I think a more generic "*I've forgotten what I'm supposed to do, how do I advance the plot?*" question would be acceptable. Questions like the one linked would seem to fit under this umbrella, and should be marked as a duplicate.

Questions put on hold as duplicates in this way may be re-opened if/when the user consults the in-game help and is unclear on how to proceed with the given instructions, and the closed question is edited to reflect this; "The game told me to do [**X**], but I can't because [**Y**]."

Answer (score 2):

As Trent said, this is probably fine.

If you're very concerned with stealing the original asker's thunder, you might just edit the original question to be slightly broader. You could probably leave the question mostly as-is, but just reframe it so the specific problem is presented as an example of the general one.

It would be best if this were done before the posting of any answers the change might invalidate. You might also want to get permission from the asker in comments, or just suggest the change to them. Remember that edits can always be rolled back. Most users seem fine with me editing their questions when I leave them a note in comments and politely suggest they roll it back if they don't like the changes.